# dynamically add multiple rows to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The following code works fine as i am able to add multiple 'tr' rows as i need it but at the same time multiple 'tbody' element is also created. So, I am trying to find a solution where i only create 'tbody' once and add multiple rows.

```
$results.each(function(){
       $('#tbl').append($('<tbody>')
                .append($('<tr>')
                .append('<td>' + Item_val + '</td>')
                .append('<td>' + Name_val + '</td>')
                .append('<td>' + No_val + '</td>'))                                
        );
});

<table id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>No</th>                    
            </tr>        
        </thead>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers do not require a `tbody` to be appended and will add one behind the scenes.

Just add your rows:

```
results.each(function(){
       $('#tbl').append($('<tr>')
                .append('<td>' + Item_val + '</td>')
                .append('<td>' + Name_val + '</td>')
                .append('<td>' + No_val + '</td>'))                                
        );
});
```

Here is a simple test showing that a `tbody` is added automatically when a TR is added:

### HTML

```
<table></table>
```

### Code:

```
alert($('table tbody').length);   // alerts 0
$('table').append('<tr>'); 
alert($('table tbody').length);   // alerts 1
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m2z2cmur/

### Notes:

- Although the HTML5 browser spec states a table may "directly contain `TR` elements", the parser in all(?) browsers use a backward-compatible approach where they insert a `tbody` when adding a `tr` (if no `tbody` is present)

Comment: Do you need to close the tr?

Comment: @Chizzle: No. jQuery will close single tags if they are not auto-closed. `"<tr>"`, `"<tr/>"` and `"<tr></tr>"` all do the same thing, so stick with a short version.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytablecontainer = $('#tbl');
var mytable = mytablecontainer.find('tbody');
if (!mytable.length){mytablecontainer.append($('<tbody>')}
mytable = mytablecontainer.find('tbody');
mytable.append()// rest of your appends
```

Comment: This will work but is kind of pointless as `tbody` should always exist (as the browsers add it automatically to `tables` when TRs are added). Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/m2z2cmur/

Comment: I never make assumptions based on browser historical behavior - look over the HTML5 specification history and there is some discussion regarding that topic - i.e. some stuff works just because browser makers just "did" it that way not because of the specification.

Comment: Just did some searching of HTML browser specs myself and find that it is specifically part of the parser spec to insert a `tbody` when adding a `tr` (if no `tbody` is present): e.g. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable

Comment: Yes, part of what I was not likely clear on was that the HTML5 spec has some of that in there.  Thanks for posting the link to the specific reference!